# How to modify grep output: get each result in each line

Tags: bash, grep, output

I'm using grep to search a pattern through a file contained in a var

Code here:

```
result=`grep "$pattern" $file`
echo $result
```

Result:
    A) somewords B)somelines C)somenumbers

print result on 1 line. I would like to have results one for line a

Like:

```
A) somewords
B) somelines
C) somenumbers
```

How can I?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just quote your `$result` variable and the newlines will be preserved:

```
result=$(grep "$pattern" $file)
echo "$result"
```

The reason this works is that when you enclose something in double quotes in bash, everything inside those quotes is treated as a single word. This means that it won't be subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html). See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Effectively when you use `$result`, it gets expanded to this (because the newlines are treated as delimiters):

```
echo A) somewords B) somelines C) somenumbers
```

When you use `"$result"` and avoid the word splitting, it gets expanded to this:

```
echo "A) somewords
B) somelines
C) somenumbers"
```

Additional note: using `$(...)` instead of backticks improves readability and also is more portable.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain me , why the double quotes modify output?

Comment: @user2302636 Without quotes the variable is subject to word splitting and globbing, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo for more info.